# Generators and Promises - trying to combine

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, generator, es6-promise

I'm trying to use a generator to perform an asynchronous operation (readdir) and print the result.

Here is my code:

```
var dirname = //some directory name;
function *gen(done) {
    let exercises = yield fs.readdir(dirname, done);
    console.log(exercises);
}

let G = gen(function(err, res) {
    G.next(res);
})

G.next();
```

This works and prints [ 'README.md', 'sol.js' ]

From what I learned, for asynchronous operations, combining generators with promises is better (trust issues). Is this true, or did I misunderstand?

Thus, I tried to combine promises with generators. I used Kyle Simpson's [Asynquence library](https://github.com/getify/asynquence/tree/master/contrib).

```
const fs = require('fs');
const ASQ = require('asynquence-contrib');

function readDirectory(dir) {
    return ASQ(function(done){
        fs.readdir(dir,done);
    });
}

function *genProm() {
    let exercises = yield readDirectory(dirname);
    console.log(exercises);
}

ASQ().runner(genProm);
```

Now, the result is 
[ null, [ 'README.md', 'sol.js' ] ]

My Questions are:

1. Why is the result different here? Where is the null coming from? And how do I get rid of it?
2. Does it make sense to combine promises and generators here?

Comment: "*I tried to combine promises with generators*" - Don't. This is so 2015. It was a hack that worked with ES6. Today you should be using `async`/`await` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me but why do you need generator here at all? Why not to use async/await?

Something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {promisify} = require('util');

const readDirectory = async dirname => await promisify(fs.readdir)(dirname);

readDirectory("someDir").then(...);
```

You can do the same even without async/await:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {promisify} = require('util');

const readDirectory = dirname => promisify(fs.readdir)(dirname);

readDirectory("someDir").then(...);
```

And finally as @Patrick Roberts suggested in comments you can simply use:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {promisify} = require('util');

const readDirectory = promisify(fs.readdir);

readDirectory("someDir").then(...);
```

Comment: Remove the `await` from the `async` function, it's completely redundant.

Comment: Yes finally I removed both. See the second listing.

Comment: Well if you're removing all redundancies, you might as well just do `const readDirectory = promisify(fs.readdir)`

Comment: Right! :) The only problem is I suppose the code in the question may be the part of some more complex code. So in original more complex code author may need both dedicated function with parameter and async/await.